Group and Count records by owner with OData in Dataverse
I want to count records grouped by owner, e.g. to answer the question: How many tasks are owned by which user?
I tried this and failed:
https://org82a557aa.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/environmentvariabledefinitions?$apply=groupby((ownerid),aggregate($count as count))

Error: $apply/groupby grouping expression 'ownerid' must evaluate to a property access value.
What I expect to get is something like this:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://org82a557aa.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/$metadata#environmentvariabledefinitions",
    "value": [
        { "ownerid": "1f387e74-750e-46a8-b92a-86eb69a4e743", "count": 6 },
        { "ownerid": "4df7be74-9fc1-ee11-9079-6045bd8f95b7", "count": 3 }
    ]
}

Any idea about how to achieve this with OData in Dataverse in a single call with server-side grouping and counting?
Or if not possible in a single OData call, what are alternatives that can easily be used in Power Automate with large datasets of >100MB of data?
I tried other variants with various other errors:
https://org82a557aa.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/environmentvariabledefinitions?$apply=groupby((_owninguser_value),aggregate($count as count))

https://org82a557aa.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/environmentvariabledefinitions?$expand=owninguser($select=fullname)&$apply=groupby((owninguser/fullname),aggregate($count as count))

